# Diablo III: Where can Bandit Shrines be found?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am aware that as of Patch 2.3.0, these Shrines appear less frequently. Where can Bandit Shrines be found; **Campaign or Adventure mode**? Also, if the answer's under Adventure mode, would it be in **Nephalem Rifts or normal Bounty-play**?

I have a hunch that the answer's Adventure mode only, but could I have some confirmation on this? (Preferably in a video/screenshots)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most telling evidence I could find was from [patch notes for patch 2.4](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/patch-notes/2-4-0) where they list an update for bandit shrine appearances under the "Adventure Mode" section.  I can tell you, only from experience, that they do not appear in rifts (nor story mode).

The [Diablo wiki](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Shrines_(Diablo_III)) states that they were added in patch 2.3 but I couldn't find anything in the notes about it (sometimes Blizzard seems to keep some things a surprise).

Note that while you won't find a bandit shrine in a rift, you can instead find goblin packs, which can be just as rewarding.